# Error: AppModule is not an NgModule

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I updated version 2.4.1 recently.

```
"@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
"@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
"@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
"angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24"
```

When I used 2.0.0, it doesn't make an error, but now, it makes an error like `GET http://localhost:4200/null 404 (Not Found)`.

Also when I try to deploy, it makes an error like '**`AppModule is not an NgModule`**'.

Even though it makes an error, it's working well on local.
If anyone knows about this, please let me know.
Thank you :)

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { DeliveryComponent } from './delivery/delivery.component';
import { AreaManagementComponent } from './area-management/area-management.component';
import { CountryComponent } from './area-management/country/country.component';

import { routing } from './app.routing';

import { AreaService } from "./area-management/area-management.service";
import { FDeliveryService } from "./f-delivery-setting/f-delivery.service";
import { ProvinceComponent } from './area-management/province/province.component';
import { SigninComponent } from './signin/signin.component';
import { CityComponent } from './area-management/city/city.component';
import { AreaComponent } from './area-management/area/area.component';
import { DeliveryAreaComponent } from './area-management/delivery-area/delivery-area.component';
import { FDeliverySettingComponent } from './f-delivery-setting/f-delivery-setting.component';
import { TermsComponent } from './terms/terms.component';
import { TermsListComponent } from './terms-list/terms-list.component';
import { TermsListService } from "./terms-list/terms-list.service";
import { TermsService } from "./terms/terms.service";
import { UserManagementComponent } from './user-management/user-management.component';
import { UserService} from "./user-management/user.service";
import { NavComponent } from './nav/nav.component';

import { MaterialModule } from '@angular/material';
import 'hammerjs';

import {
  DialogModule,
  ButtonModule,
  DataTableModule,
  InputTextModule,
  TabViewModule,
  DropdownModule,
  EditorModule,
  SharedModule,
  AutoCompleteModule,
  PanelMenuModule,
  MenuModule,
  ContextMenuModule,
  PasswordModule,
  FileUploadModule,
  InputTextareaModule,
  RadioButtonModule,
  CalendarModule,
  CheckboxModule,
  ConfirmDialogModule,
  ConfirmationService, InputMaskModule, BlockUIModule
} from "primeng/primeng";
import { SignupComponent } from './signin/signup.component';
import { LicenseComponent } from './license/license.component';
import { TermsShowComponent } from './terms-show/terms-show.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from "./signin/auth-guard.service";
import { AuthService } from "./signin/auth.service";
import { UserDetailComponent } from './user-detail/user-detail.component';
import { LicenseDetailComponent } from './license/license-detail/license-detail.component';
import { UserDetailService } from "./user-detail/user-detail.service";
import { LicenseService } from "./license/license.service";
import { BranchManagementComponent } from './branch-management/branch-management.component';
import { BranchService } from "./branch-management/branch.service";
import { BranchDetailComponent } from './branch-management/branch-detail/branch-detail.component';
import { InternalComponent } from './home/internal/internal.component';
import { ExternalComponent } from './home/external/external.component';
import { ClassificationComponent } from './classification/classification.component';
import { ClientComponent } from './client/client.component';
import { DmBillingComponent } from './payment-billing/dm-billing/dm-billing.component';
import { PartnerBillingComponent } from './payment-billing/partner-billing/partner-billing.component';
import { WowbillingComponent } from './payment-billing/wowbilling/wowbilling.component';
import { DailyReportingComponent } from './daily-reporting/daily-reporting.component';
import { AccountClosingComponent } from './account-closing/account-closing.component';
import { AccountingComponent } from "./accounting-balance/accounting-balance.component";
import { DeliveryService } from "./delivery/delivery.service";
import { UserAddComponent } from './user-add/user-add.component';
import { NavService } from "./nav/nav.service";
import { PartnerService } from "./shared/partner.service";
import { ClientService } from "./shared/client.service";
import { PartnerComponent } from './partner/partner.component';
import { PartnerDetailComponent } from './partner/partner-detail/partner-detail.component';
import { NewBranchComponent } from './branch-management/new-branch/new-branch.component';
import { ForgetPasswordComponent } from './signin/forget-password/forget-password.component';
import { DeliveryDetailComponent } from './delivery/delivery-detail/delivery-detail.component';
import {FileUploadService} from "./shared/file-upload.service";
import { PartnerEditComponent } from './partner/partner-edit/partner-edit.component';
import {AgmCoreModule} from "angular2-google-maps/core/core-module";

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    DeliveryComponent,
    AreaManagementComponent,
    CountryComponent,
    ProvinceComponent,
    SigninComponent,
    CityComponent,
    AreaComponent,
    DeliveryAreaComponent,
    FDeliverySettingComponent,
    TermsComponent,
    TermsListComponent,
    UserManagementComponent,
    NavComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    LicenseComponent,
    TermsShowComponent,
    UserDetailComponent,
    LicenseDetailComponent,
    BranchManagementComponent,
    BranchDetailComponent,
    InternalComponent,
    ExternalComponent,
    AccountingComponent,
    ClassificationComponent,
    ClientComponent,
    DmBillingComponent,
    PartnerBillingComponent,
    WowbillingComponent,
    DailyReportingComponent,
    AccountClosingComponent,
    UserAddComponent,
    PartnerComponent,
    PartnerDetailComponent,
    NewBranchComponent,
    ForgetPasswordComponent,
    DeliveryDetailComponent,
    PartnerEditComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    routing,
    MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    AgmCoreModule.forRoot({
      apiKey: Key
    }),

    //primeNG
    InputTextareaModule,
    InputTextModule,
    DataTableModule,
    DialogModule,
    DropdownModule,
    ButtonModule,
    TabViewModule,
    EditorModule,
    SharedModule,
    PanelMenuModule,
    MenuModule,
    ContextMenuModule,
    PasswordModule,
    FileUploadModule,
    RadioButtonModule,
    CalendarModule,
    CheckboxModule,
    ConfirmDialogModule,
    InputMaskModule
  ],
  providers: [
    AreaService,
    FDeliveryService,
    TermsListService,
    TermsService,
    UserService,
    AuthGuardService,
    AuthService,
    UserDetailService,
    LicenseService,
    BranchService,
    DeliveryService,
    NavService,
    PartnerService,
    ClientService,
    ConfirmationService,
    FileUploadService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**Packages.json**

```
{
  "name": "five-delivery-admin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.4.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.4.1",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",
    "angular2-google-maps": "^0.17.0",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "bourbon": "^4.2.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.0.5",
    "es6-shim": "^0.35.2",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "moment": "^2.17.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.10",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.0",
    "primeng": "^1.1.0",
    "pubnub-angular2": "^1.0.0-beta.7",
    "quill": "^1.1.8",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.9",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.2",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "typescript": "^2.0.10",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.2.30",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/moment-timezone": "^0.2.33",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "codelyzer": "~0.0.26",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "4.0.9",
    "ts-loader": "^1.3.3",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "4.2.0",
    "typescript": "2.0.10"
  }
}
```

**angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "name": "five-delivery-admin"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": ["assets"],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "styles.scss",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/omega/theme.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.core.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.snow.css",
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.bubble.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [
        "../node_modules/quill/dist/quill.min.js",
        "../node_modules/hammerjs/hammer.min.js"
      ],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "mapRoot": "./",
    "module": "es6",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "../dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "../node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
}
```

**typings.json**

```
{
  "globalDependencies": {
    "es6-collections": "registry:dt/es6-collections#0.5.1+20160316155526",
    "es6-promise": "registry:dt/es6-promise#0.0.0+20160614011821"
  }
}
```

Comment: Surely the problem should not be in angular-cli generated files that you posted here. Might help if you post something related to your stack trace.

Comment: @jali-ai I have no idea which info I should post here. :( I wanted to use google maps with angular2. So I installed google maps and update some. I searched about this problem, and many of angular users have same issue now and still it doesn't solved. Do you have any idea to fix this issue?

Comment: Attach your `AppModule` code

Comment: @ParthaSarathiGhosh I edited and added post

Comment: in your package.json your ` "angular-cli": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21",` are still in beta.. maybe edit it to the correct version,clear node_modules and do `npm install` again..

Comment: @SurajRao I installed both using npm install angular-cli@latest --save; npm install angular2@latest. I deleted angular2": "^2.0.0-beta.21 cause it is deprecated. However, it's still not working

Also, angular-cli version is correct version as far as I know.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found a solution. **Change the version of typescript to 2.0.10**
I reply for myself and others who are stuck this problem :)

1. Check typescript version using `tsc -v`
2. Remove typescript
3. Install `npm install typescript@2.0.10 --save`

If someone has a better solution, let me know :)

Comment: I got it working by using `v1.0.0-beta.21` of `angular-cli` instead of pushing back the version of Typescript.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! 
My angular-cli version is 1.0.0-beta.24, I guess that angular-cli is not compatible with typescript yet. :(

Comment: At least is isn't compatible with latest Typescript version. Hopefully that will get sorted out soon!

Comment: also not working with cli in version  1.0.0-beta.28.3 - fingers crossed that the RC  coming soon has the fix

Comment: MartinHN, I look forward to trying your solution. Currently, I am struggling to revert to a previous version: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42830647/npm-unable-to-revert-to-previous-version-of-node-package-angular-cli
If you were to post an answer I would happy to give it the thumbs up

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This issue has now been fixed. [issue ref](https://github.com/vlio20/ng2-date-picker/issues/8#issuecomment-285011287)

Creadit to MartinHN comment on Minyu Jeon's answer.

> Use v1.0.0-beta.21 of angular-cli

I was previously using v1.0.0-beta.28.3 and migrated back to this as follows:

1. Revert version of angular-cli as follows: [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42830647/2945345)
2. Create new angular app using the cli.
3. Make several changes to the code which are required for this older version, including:

   import './polyfills.ts';

at the top of main.ts
Errors will show up with details when trying to run the app. They didn't take long to resolve.

Answer (score 0):

add tag to the file tsconfig.json

```
"skipMetadataEmit":false
```

will be like that

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
      "skipMetadataEmit":false ,
      "genDir": "./dist/ngfactory",    
      "entryModule": "./src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
```