# Angular 2 justgage, ERROR in justgageModule is not an NgModule?

Tags: angular, justgage

I am unable to Deploy an app because of a justgage component error, so far it displays ok along with the options, but this message comes whenever I try to deploy.

Note: According to some research I have found that this message appears with some modules and it is because of the typescript version.

Do you know how to include it without that error?

I use it according to specifications:

1 I install the component:

```
npm install angular2-justgage
```

Then I include it as a module:

```
import { JustgageModule } from 'angular2-justgage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ JustgageModule ]
  // ... I have additional modules
})
    export class AppModule {
      options = {
      min: 0,
      title: 'Visitors'
};
```

in the template I include the component with proper selector:

```
<justgage [options]="options" [max]="max" [value]="value"></justgage>
```

here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "crowd-lending",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.55",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.3",
    "angular2-fullcalendar": "^1.1.1",
    "angular2-notifications": "^0.4.53",
    "chart.js": "^2.5.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ng2-bootstrap": "^1.4.0",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.5.0",
    "ng2-select": "^1.2.0",
    "primeng": "^2.0.3",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.28.3",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you read http://stackoverflow.com/q/41420619/573032

Comment: Yes and it did not work for me, what I did and really worked is that instead of importing it as a module, I include it as  a Declaration.

Comment: @RomanC Despite that I want to include it as a module because I do not want to have doubts in case this happends again.

Comment: looks like too weird but I don't have such problem.

Comment: I wish I could send you an screenshot from my ng build from before and after

Comment: the angular2-justgage module must have an index.ts file that exports the module

Answer (score 0):

looking in your package.json I can't see angular2-justgage or it dependencies like justgage and raphael. your problem might lay in that departement hope this is still relevant for you